# SSIS: Exclude lookup source column from destination

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Reading from a DB on one server and need to join one of the columns to a table on another server using a lookup. That part is fine, I'm having trouble configuring/customizing the flat file destination after the lookup is done.

Doing a lookup on a column and want to exclude my source lookup column `OLE DB Source.pcp_phone` from the flat file destination. Right now it returns both the `OLE DB Source.pcp_phone` and `Lookup.pcp_phone`. Need just the`Lookup.pcp_phone`.

If I ignore `OLE DB Source.pcp_phone` from the mappings, `Lookup.pcp_phone` is lost as well.

(Update) I deleted the mapping between the `OLE DB Source.pcp_phone` in the second photo and the value of that column is now blank while leaving the actual lookup present, but the `OLE DB Source.pcp_phone` is still showing in the column header and the value for that column is still present in the records with a ','.

How can I remove the presence of the `OLE DB Source.pcp_phone` completely from the file destination? Another thing, is there a way to rename the `Lookup.pcp_phone` column in the flat file destination, needs to just be pcp_phone.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Cam you show us a snapchot of the dataflowtask? this is unclear

Comment: Try to add more information please what you are trying to achieve. Provide some context. Thanks.

Comment: I added more details, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After the updates you provided, to organize your destination flat file columns (rename , delete , add , edit) you have to go to the `flat file connection manager` used by the `flat file destination` , go to the `Advanced Tab` and edit your columns.

[image]